# Magento font icon not showing in new store view

Tags: magento, fonts, icons

I have setup one magento store view.
But in new store view font icon not showing.

So provide appropriate suggestion for fix this problem.

I just inform you in main store its working fine.

For some reason i can not share website link.

**Thanks.**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue.

Add below code in your .htaccess file. for allow Access Control.

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

**Thanks.**